# Error when upgrading from magento 2.2.5 to magento 2.2.8

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, magento-2.2.5, magento2.2.8

When upgrading Magento version 2.2.5 to version 2.2.8 it throws the following error

Problem 1

> ```
> - Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping-m2[1.3.10, 1.3.7].
> - Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping-m2[1.3.10, 1.3.7].
> - Can only install one of: temando/module-shipping-m2[1.3.7, 1.3.10].
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.8 requires temando/module-shipping-m2 1.3.10 -> satisfiable by
> ```
>
> temando/module-shipping-m2[1.3.10].
>       - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.8 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.8].
>       - Installation request for temando/module-shipping-m2 (locked at 1.3.7) -> satisfiable by temando/module-shipping-m2[1.3.7].

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I've got the same issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

From the lines that you have posted I would guess that in your `composer.json` you require the package `temando/module-shipping` with version constraint `1.3.7` while the package `magento/product-community-edition` requires a higher version.
Check your `composer.json` for a line similar to:

```json
"temando/module-shipping": "1.3.7"
```

and either delete it or change it to

```json
"temando/module-shipping": "^1.3.7"
```

Should this not be the case, you can always check which packages require a specific package in which version by executing the following:

```bash
composer why temando/module-shipping
```

Comment: 0


thanks for reply i have successfully upgraded version

Answer (score 0):

**Remove This Module Entry in `core_config_data` Table**

**And Then Run This Command :-**

```
composer update

composer install

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: thanks for answer

Comment: working or not ?